# Java: How to update custom ListCellRenderer?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I implemented my own ListCellRenderer for my chat app. I use a JList to list all users. The cell renderer consists mainly of an icon that displays if a particular user is currently on- or offline and his/her name. The list is controlled by a DefaultListModel which I use to provide the JList with the necessary information.

But when the list model does change its state (e.g. a user goes offline), the list cell renderer seems not to be invoked?

Somebody any idea how to solve this problem? Tried to call updateUI() on the JList instance, but did not helped.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the code. The renderer should be invoked when the model changes. You probably forgot to fire an event to signal that the model has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cell renderer probably works fine. What is not working is the ListModel. The `DefaultListModel` does not detect changes to the internal state of the model objects. You need to call `fireContentsChanged` on the list model. Probably you need to add listeners to your model objects and maybe you even have to extend the `DefaultListModel`; as I don't see the code of it I don't know how yours look.

You should not just call a random method with a name that sounds good (`updateUI` does something very different).

Comment: many thanks for the fast reply. I will try to call fireContentsChanged, since this method is protected I will in fact have to extend the DefaultListModel.

Comment: btw. the javadoc says for JList.UpdateUI() function the following: If the current cell renderer was installed by the developer (rather than the look and feel itself), this also causes the cell renderer and its children to be updated... This not only sounds good, but also helpful for my problem. don't you think?

Comment: No. Not the display of the list will be updated but the UI delegates of the renderer component. The "..." in your quote are: ", by calling {@code SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI} on it.". That is not "repainting the list" or such. I am sorry if the last paragraph in my answer sounds a little harsh. / IMO most of the time it is better to extend from `AbstractTableModel` if you have mutable list elements; easier to implement reasonable update method that way (without too much listeners).